# Require at least one element in ZF2 FieldSet

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-form2

**The problem**

I have a `Form` and a `FieldSet`. I would like to validate that the `FieldSet` is not empty. Also, I want to validate each field in the `FieldSet`.

So far, whatever I have tried is validating one or the other, but not both. If `elements` is present in the Form's input filter specification, then it validates that `elements` is not empty, but does not validate the `bar` and `baz` fields of `FieldSet`. And, of course, the other way around. Any clue as to how to approach this issue would be much appreciated.

**The Form**

```
class FooForm extends Form implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->add([
            'name'     => 'elements',
            'type'     => Collection::class,
            'required' => true,
            'options'  => [
                'target_element' => [
                    'type' => SomeElementFieldSet::class
                ]
            ]
        ]);
    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return [
            [
                'name'        => 'elements',
                'required'    => true,
                'validators'  => [
                    ['name' => 'NotEmpty']
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

**The FieldSet**

```
class SomeElementFieldSet extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->add(['name' => 'bar']);
        $this->add(['name' => 'baz']);
    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return [
            [
                'name'       => 'bar',
                'required'   => true,
                'validators' => [
                    ['name' => 'NotEmpty']
                ]
            ],
            [
                'name'       => 'baz',
                'required'   => true,
                'validators' => [
                    ['name' => 'NotEmpty']
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Added full validation spec.

Comment: You might need to update your example. Your form is adding `SomeElement::class` but I think you ment `SomeElementFieldset::class` or did you register it that way within your configuration? Nevertheless its a minor issue, you might wanne read the docs about [Form Collections](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html#creating-fieldsets). You might set option `count` for the fieldset to 1 so you atleast got one entry of the fieldset. Aswell as in the docs they don't add the fieldset to the forms `::getInputFilterSpecifications()`.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, it was indeed a typo. Honestly, I went through the documentation a few times and googled for a few hours without success, before coming here. :) I tried setting `count` to 1 or even more, just in case, it did not help. And the problem with leaving the fieldset out of `getInputFilterSpecification()` is that then it does not validate the count and the fieldset might come through empty.

Comment: Did you set the required options for the fields within `getInputFilterSpecification()` of your fieldset? Might help to show which validators/filters you bind to the fields: *bar* and *baz*, instead of a comment: "// validation for bar & baz". For example some people do use `NotEmpty` validators which is pretty much like the required options.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I've added more code. Although it doesn't really matter which validators I put there, they just don't run at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting some hints on Google and digging through the source code, I found a solution. Unfortunately the `zend-inputfilter` implementation is a little buggy and won't work nicely with `getInputFilterSpecification()`, but we can just construct our own `InputFilter` and return that directly:

**The Form**

```
class FooForm extends BaseForm
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->add([
            'name'    => 'elements',
            'type'    => Collection::class,
            'options' => [
                'target_element' => [
                    'type' => SomeElementFieldSet::class
                ]
            ]
        ]);
    }

    public function getInputFilter()
    {
        if (!$this->filter) {
            $this->filter = new InputFilter();

            /** @var Collection $elementsCollection */
            $elementsCollection = $this->fieldsets['elements'];

            /** @var SomeElementFieldSet $elementsFieldSet */
            $elementsFieldSet = $elementsCollection->getTargetElement();

            $collectionFilter = new CollectionInputFilter();
            $collectionFilter->setIsRequired(true);
            $collectionFilter->setInputFilter(
                $elementsFieldSet->getInputFilterSpecification()
            );

            $this->filter->add($collectionFilter, 'elements');
        }

        return $this->filter;
    }
}
```

This will validate that there is at least one element in the collection. And will validate all the elements one by one by the FieldSet's specification.

One problem persists, though. Whenever the collection is empty, the validation will return `false`, but will not return any messages. This is due to a bug in the `zend-inputfilter` component. Issues reported [here](https://github.com/zendframework/zendframework/issues/6527) and [here](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-inputfilter/issues/94). But that is another problem altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setValidationGroup()` method in the `Form` object by specifying an array of input fields you want to validate. Please refer to the [Doc](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/in-depth-guide/zend-form-zend-form-fieldset.html)!

**You may give a try this way**. Though I have added some extra fields to the form for testing purpose only.

```
class FooForm extends Form implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
     public function __construct($name = null, $options = array())
     {

        parent::__construct($name, $options);

        $this->add(['name' => 'title']);

        $this->add([
            'name'     => 'elements',
            'type'     => Collection::class,
            'required' => true,
            'options'  => [
                'target_element' => [
                    'type' => SomeElementFieldSet::class,
                ],
            ],
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'type' => 'submit',
            'name' => 'submit',
            'attributes' => [
                 'value' => 'Post'
            ],
        ]);

        // I pointed this. Here you can specify fields to be validated
        $this->setValidationGroup([
            'title',
            'elements' => [
                'bar',
            ],
        ]);         
     }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return [
            [
                'name'       => 'title',
                'required'   => true,
                'validators' => [
                    ['name' => 'NotEmpty']
                ]
            ],
        ];
    }     
}
```

And your fieldset class should be

```
class SomeElementFieldSet extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->add(['name' => 'bar']);
        $this->add(['name' => 'baz']);
    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return [
            [
                'name'       => 'bar',
                'required'   => true,
                'validators' => [
                    ['name' => 'NotEmpty']
                ]
            ],
            [
                'name'       => 'baz',
                'required'   => true,
                'validators' => [
                    ['name' => 'NotEmpty']
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Hope this would help!

Comment: Validation groups are not gonna solve this issue, as I don't want to validate a subset of fields, but rather validate that fieldset has some elements in it and then validate all the fields of the fieldset.

Comment: Are you sure? Edited code and changed the DOC. Please have a look! I have tested with ZF2.4. It works. Let us know. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the extra code, will give it a try again and let you know. :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but this code did not work. It never validated an empty collection. Thanks anyway! ;)

Comment: I am very sorry that it did not help you! :(

Comment: No worries, I appreciate the effort regardless. ;)